# Retrieve User's Work Phone on change of People or Group field in NewItem form using JSLink

Tags: sharepoint-online, people-picker, jslink, newform, sharepoint-list

I have one SharePoint list in which there are two fields:

- User (People or Group)
- Work Phone (Single Line of Text)

On default `NewItem form` of this list, When we add User in `User` field then that user's Work Phone should be automatically comes in Work Phone input text on change of User field.

How to achieve this using `JSLink` ?

How to call `onchange` event on list's default people or group field and get the user details at `onchange` ? I have tried to get user on people or group change with following code:

```
// it does not calling on auto complete
$(".sp-peoplepicker-topLevel input").change(function () {
    console.log("Onchange event");        
});
```

Change event was called but on selecting user (on autocomplete), this event does not calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieve the requirement:

I have added a `JSLink` file to list.

In JSLink code,

--> **Created a `blur` event for People or Group field `User`**

```
    // Get Selected user in People or Group field
    var inputP = $(".sp-peoplepicker-topLevel input");
    $(inputP).blur(function () {
        var PickerDiv = $("div[title='User']"); //User is people field.....
        var PickerInstance = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[PickerDiv[0].id];
        if ($("div[title='User'] .ms-entity-resolved").attr("title") != "") {
            userEmail = PickerInstance.GetAllUserInfo()[0].EntityData.Email;
            console.log("User Email: " + userEmail);
            getWorkPhone(); // Get the work phone by email and set to work phone field
        }
    });
```

--> **In `getWorkPhone` function, retrieves the User's work phone based on Email**

```
function getWorkPhone() {
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var website = clientContext.get_web();
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'EMail\'/>' + '<Value Type=\'Text\'>' + userEmail + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>'); // CAMLQuery based on Email
    var userInfoList = website.get_siteUserInfoList();
    collListItem = userInfoList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(website);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);

    function onRequestSucceeded() {
        var item = collListItem.itemAt(0);
        var OfficePhone = item.get_fieldValues().WorkPhone;
        console.log("Office Phone: " + OfficePhone);
        // Set Work phone to list's `Work phone` field
        $("input[title='Work phone']").attr({ value: OfficePhone }); 
    }

    function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
        console.log('Error: ' + args.get_message());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is working but onclick of Phone field.

1.Edit New form page.

2.Add content Editor web part & then add below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$("input[title='Phone']").click(function(){
     var CurrentUserLoginName="";


     var PickerDiv = $("div[title='User']"); //User is people field.....
var PickerInstance = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[PickerDiv[0].id];
if($("div[title='User'] .ms-entity-resolved").attr("title")!=""){

CurrentUserLoginName=PickerInstance.GetAllUserInfo()[0].Key;
}

$().SPServices({
 operation : "GetUserProfileByName",
                async : false,
                AccountName : CurrentUserLoginName,
                completefunc : function (xData, Status) {                                          

  $("input[title='Phone']").attr({value: getUserProfileValueFromXML(xData.responseXML, "WorkPhone")});

                  }
            });                                

            function getUserProfileValueFromXML(responseXML, property) {
                            var thisValue = $(responseXML).SPFilterNode("PropertyData").filter(function () {
                                                            return $(this).find("Name").text() == property;
                                            }).find("Values").text();
                            return thisValue;
            }  
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Break up you challenge in multiple parts.
(*and given your answers here on SO you can code*)

1. [Set an onchange event on the PeoplePicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onchange)
2. [get the proper username](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=peoplepicker+username)
3. get the user properties

   3a. [using JSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=jsom+user+properties)

   3b. [using REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=rest+user+properties)
4. proces returned properties
5. Set the WorkPhone field

WYSIWYG editing with the Cisar extension makes all this a lot easier:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo